# Python: argparse switch default True otherwise consume all arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I would like a switch that does the following:

1. Defaults to False
2. If the switch is present with no additional arguments then it is set to True
3. Collects any number of additional arguments into a list

I can do 1 and 2 with `nargs='?'` but not 3:

```
group.add_argument('--my_switch', nargs='?', dest='myswitch', default=False, const=True)
print(args.myswitch)

>python myscript.py 
>False
>python myscript.py --my_switch
>True
>python myscript.py --my_switch foo
>foo
>python myscript.py --my_switch foo bar
>error: unrecognized arguments: bar
```

I can do 1 and 3 with `nargs='+'` but not 2:

```
group.add_argument('--my_switch', nargs='+', dest='myswitch', default=False)
print(args.myswitch)

>python myscript.py 
>False
>python myscript.py --my_switch
>argument --my_switch: expected at least one argument
>python myscript.py --my_switch foo
>['foo']
>python myscript.py --my_switch foo bar
>['foo', 'bar']
```

I can do 1 and 3 with `nargs='*'` but almost 2:

```
group.add_argument('--my_switch', nargs='+', dest='myswitch', default=False)
print(args.myswitch)

>python myscript.py 
>False
>python myscript.py --my_switch
>[]
>python myscript.py --my_switch foo
>['foo']
>python myscript.py --my_switch foo bar
>['foo', 'bar']
```

Does argparse offer a solution to this? I can't use `const` with `+` or `*`.

One work around is to use `nargs='*'` and set

```
if isinstance(args.myswitch, list) and len(args.myswitch) == 0: 
    args.myswitch = True
```

but it seems like this should be a common enough situation to offer a built in method.

Comment: Looks like you've explored all the options.   You could write a custom Action class that uses `const` along with the * store,  But I think your last attempt is  prettier.